# How do I enable line numbers in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I can't seem to find that option.

Surely it's in there?

Comment: you got 4 answers in a minute..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That would be Tools > Options

Text Editor > All Languages > Line Numbers (at the bottom right)

Answer (score 10):

Don't forget to check "[x] Show all settings" at the bottom of the form, otherwise you won't be able to see "All Languages".

Comment: That was it! (in 2008 Express, happy they didn't remove it)

Answer (score 8):

Go to Tools - Options - Text Editor - All Languages - General, and check Line numbers to show line numbers for all files.

If you just want to see (or not see) the line numbers of a specific file, you can override this global setting by going to the Text Editor -  - General page.

[Did you know... how to show line numbers in the editor?](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2007/08/30/did-you-know-how-to-show-line-numbers-in-the-editor.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All languages.  Near the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Main Menu > Tools > Options
Text Editor (Tree) > C# > Display group (Line numbers checkbox)

that was easy :)