# how to get line number in code editor in vs2008?

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable line numbers in VS2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874/how-do-i-enable-line-numbers-in-vs2008)

how to get line number in code editor in vs2008?

Comment: -1 Please search. Google lists SO result as the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to tool>option>text editor check 'line number'

Answer (score 1):

Tools...Options...Text Editor....All Languages... Display... Line Numbers.